# Understanding the implementation of traditional and enhanced iterations on C# and Java

Tags: c#, java, compiler-construction

I'm feeling quite confused about the way either **C#**'s `foreach` and **Java**'s *enhanced for* works and even more frustrating is to realize why I haven't came across this detail before.

But anyway the fact of the matter is, I'd really like to understand why this apparently similar flow control statements work so differently. For illustration purposes let's assume we need to iterate through an array of integers, with both implementations being something like:

**C# 4.0 (code)**

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] foobar = new int[] {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21};
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[DEBUG] type: {0}", foobar.GetType()));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[DEBUG] length: {0}", foobar.Length));
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < foobar.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(String.Format("{0} ", foobar[i]));
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);

            foreach (var i in foobar) {
                Console.Write(String.Format("{0} ", foobar[i]));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**C# 4.0 (output)**

```
[DEBUG] type: System.Int32[]
[DEBUG] length: 9
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21
0 1 1 1 2 5 21
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Dotnet.Samples.Sandbox.Program.Main(String[] args) in e:\My Dropbox\Work\P
rojects\scm\git\sandbox\Dotnet.Samples.Sandbox\Dotnet.Samples.Sandbox\Program.cs
:line 51

Press any key to continue . . .
```

**JAVA SE6 (code)**

```
class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] foobar = new int[] {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21};
        System.out.println("[DEBUG] type: " + (foobar.getClass().isArray() ? "Array " : "") +  foobar.getClass().getComponentType());
        System.out.println("[DEBUG] length: " + foobar.length);
        try {    
            for (int i = 0; i < foobar.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(String.format("%d ", foobar[i]));
            }
            System.out.print(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            for (int i : foobar) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%d ", foobar[i]));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**JAVA SE6 (output)**

```
[DEBUG] type: Array int
[DEBUG] length: 9
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 
0 1 1 1 2 5 21 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13
```

Comment: I think this would actually be better off on the main StackOverflow site. It's not so much about "algorithm and data structure concepts" as the usage of a specific language feature in C# and Java; also, I suspect you wouldn't have had to wait 18 minutes for an answer over there. :-)

Comment: @Carson63000: Thanks for the comment. I'd take in consideration any advice from someone with your reputation and I'd gladly be willing to move the question to StackOverflow but given that people started to reply here I don't think it'd be respectful of me to do that now.

Comment: It took me a hell of a long time to understand what you were asking. I would have asked: "In what respect do they work differently, given your example? I see exactly the same output.". Still, you could have figured this out by reading the documentation. `foreach` is quite fundamental in C#, I can't speak for Java.

Comment: @Tom W: I'm sorry to read that -- luckily there's other contributors that have understood the question. So what is the point of your comment? I don't see how it could be a constructive contribution at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the C# version..

```
foreach (var i in foobar)
{
    Console.Write(String.Format("{0} ", foobar[i]));
}
```

..should be..

```
foreach (var i in foobar)
{
    Console.Write(String.Format("{0} ", i));
}
```

Doing a `foreach` over an array of integers, as you are, does not iterate over array indices: it iterates over the integers.

Given the array..

```
int[] foobar = new int[] {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21};
```

..your code was:

```
Printing element 0: 0
Printing element 1: 1
Printing element 1: 1
Printing element 2: 1
Printing element 3: 2
Printing element 5: 5
Printing element 8: 21
Printing element 13: IndexOutOfRangeException !!
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using the value as an indexer, foreach gives you each value in the array, not each index

if you write

```
   foreach (var i in foobar) {
        Console.Write(String.Format("{0} ", i));
    }
```

it should be correct

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I should add this as a comment to Carson63000 or add as an answer, but the Java has the same issue.

> for(int i : foobar)
>   {
>          System.out.print(i);
>   }

As a side note, I find Java's "enhanced for" to be less intuitive than C#'s foreach. I think after you deal with Java, you start to understand what "for(int i: foobar)" means, but I don't think anybody would argue that foreach is more straightforward.

There are times when foreach and "enhanced for" are not the best choice when using a for loop though. If you need access to more than one value in the array, you are best to use the traditional for loop because the foreach/enhanced for will only allow you to access one value at a time.

Comment: Yep, sorry, I meant to add "..and while I don't know Java, I am confident that it is exactly the same issue", but I forgot, once I'd finished formatting all my code snippets. :-)